# Arangosh query times out after 30 mins

Tags: javascript, arangodb

**AQL query**:

```
arangosh --server.endpoint tcp://localhost:8529 --server.username username --server.database db --server.password pwd --javascript.execute test_aql.js
```

**Error**:

```
2021-08-25T14:22:59Z [5430] ERROR JavaScript exception in file '/usr/share/arangodb3/js/client/modules/@arangodb/arangosh.js' at 99,7: ArangoError 2001: Error reading from: 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529' 'timeout during read'
2021-08-25T14:22:59Z [5430] ERROR !      throw error;
2021-08-25T14:22:59Z [5430] ERROR !      ^
```

### Problem

1. We have a long running query which we are trying to automate the Arango Query interface from UI doesn't support the number of lines in the data, So had to switch to the arangosh to test this query. We are able to run small queries but this query takes about 9 hours to run and it times out very quickly.
2. Is there a way to add a long timeout for the tcp connection.
3. Is there a way to run the javascript file in the native environment without timeout issue.

As I didn't find any forums where I can post this , If anybody has come across a solution or any other way to try this. It would help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `--server.connection-timeout` option?

https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangosh-options.html